# resize /dev/sda8 to add 40GB

Tags: debian, command-line, partition, partition-table, resize2fs

I have a question regarding the enlargement of a partition without LVM.

I have already read through some things how to proceed here, but I am still unsure, so I ask the question myself.

I have /dev/sda with a storage size of 160GB.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, the number of sectors on /dev/sda is 335544320.

And with cfdisk, I see that 40GB of free space is available.

[image]

Now I want to enlarge /dev/sda8 with 40GB. I know that the start of /dev/sda8 is important for the partition table. But here I get a bit into thinking. What do I have to specify as final value to have +40GB more for /dev/sda8? The data will not be deleted if the value is not smaller than before. But still I am unsure here.

Could you please tell me, according to screenshot, how to proceed so that I can achieve the desired goal?

Thank you all for your time and knowledge!

Comment: the free space sou;d be located right after the partition. Otherwise you can't add. Or if you force the things you will loose information from other partitions

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Answer (score 1):

With partitions the free space needs to be directly after the partition you are trying to grow so you can't simply grow the sda8 partition because the 40 GiB free space is at the end of the disk. If I were you I either would completely repartition the disk, or use some advanced storage stack like LVM, MD RAID or btrfs volumes to join sda8 and the free space.

If you don't want to do that, you'll need to resize the extended partition (`sda2`) and then move partitions 9, 11, 12 and 13 (10 is actually out of order and starts on lower sector than 8) one by one to the end of the disk and then you can resize `sda8`. `cfdisk` cannot do this, you'd need to use GParted which can also move partitions, but even with GParted this would be a risky operation and it would take a long time (moving a partition requires copying data to the new position). So I would really recommend making a backup and starting over.

Comment: You have a lot of small partitions. Do you really need those. It makes it harder to manage as one may fill up before another. Often better to not have too many, so the unused space in the partition can be shared with each folder. But it becomes a balance on what your want. If totally redoing drive, I also suggest gpt of old MBR(msdos). GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR I started converting drives to gpt in 2010.